# Mapping value to pixel pairs - How to implement the data structure

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, mapping

I have a function f(x,y), where x and y are pixel coordinates (like in OpenCV `cv::Point(i,j)`), that maps a float value to every pixel pair (x,y). My question is: What is the correct data structure to represent this mapping? I want to have something like an array with multiple types, which is not possible with standard arrays. I want to use it as in the following example:

```
mat[cv::Point(i,j)][cv::Point(k,l)] = 5.0f;
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: So you are not using OpenCV, but your own array?

Comment: I'm using OpenCV, but I don't know how to use a matrix in this case when it comes to indexing with point pairs.

Comment: So you want a Mat with more than 2 dimensions? or what is a pixel pair in your opinion? x and y are 2 points, so x has x and y and y has x and y coords, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @Gombat, a simple approach is to use `std::map`, and use a a `std::pair<cv::Point, cv::Point>` as key.

You need., however to provide a custom comparator since `cv::Point` does not provide the `operator<`.

Take a look at this code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <map>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

bool lessPoints(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.x == rhs.x) ? lhs.y < rhs.y : lhs.x < rhs.x;
}

struct lessPairPoints
{
    bool operator()(const pair<Point, Point>& lhs, const pair<Point, Point>& rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.first == rhs.first) ? lessPoints(lhs.second, rhs.second) : lessPoints(lhs.first, rhs.first);
    }
};

typedef map<pair<Point, Point>, float, lessPairPoints> MapPoints;

int main()
{
    MapPoints map1;

    map1[{Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1)}] = 0.3;
    map1[{Point(1, 2), Point(1, 1)}] = 0.1;

    for (const auto& el : map1)
    {
        cout << el.first.first << ", " << el.first.second << " -> " << el.second << endl;
    }

    cout << map1[{Point(0,0), Point(1,1)}] << endl;

    auto pp = make_pair(Point(1,2), Point(1,1)); 
    cout << map1[pp] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using a `std::map`:

```
std::map< Point, std::map< Point, float > > map;
map[Point(0,0)][Point(0,0)] = 5.0f;
```

But to do so, `Point` needs an `operator<`:

```
struct Point
{
  Point(const size_t _x, const size_t _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
  size_t x, y;

  bool operator<(const Point& rhs) const
  {
    // first of all, order regarding x
    if ( x < rhs.x ) return true;
    if ( x > rhs.x ) return false;
    // if x is equal, order regarding y
    if ( y < rhs.y ) return true;
    return false;
  }
};
```

You can of course check, whether there is an element `Point(0,0)` in the map by using `find()`:

```
if( map.find(Point(0,0)) == map.end() ){ /*Element not found*/ }
```

---

If you can use c++11, an `std::unorderd_map` is also an option, since you don't need an `operator<` for the key class.

---

You could even use `std::pair<Point,Point>`as a key for the map.

---

Another option would be to use a 4D Array like this:

```
mat[i][j][k][l] = 5.0f;
```

Comment: It could be surprising to put (2,3) in a map and find that (3,2) is also there.

Comment: Why so? (2,3) and (3,2) are completely different positions.

Comment: They're the same according to your ordering.

Answer (score -1):

You just need the `width` of your screen where the pixels are on.
Such a function is easily implemented, since `width * height` equals the amount of pixels, you can write `x + y * width` to represent any pixel on the map.